# Need to output javascript date object from a php json_encode call

Tags: php, javascript, json

```
$array = array('start'=>"new Date(".date("Y",strtotime($start_date)).")");
$myJson = json_encode($array);
```

The returned json is a string, how can i convert the dates to objects? I'm using the jquery calendar plugin and it wants a date object. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Send a date string normally with json and then parse it with javascript:
`var d = Date.parse("Jul 8, 2005");`

Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parse.asp

Comment: This is great to know! I used a few str_replaces() to just strip the quotes out of the json output but next time I will remember this. Thanks!

Comment: You referenced w3schools. W3schools is a terrible resource as it teaches syntax and not design. W3schools would recommend you send a js snippet and then `eval(snippet)` it.... -1

Comment: @sg3s It was the first result on the search...

Comment: @Jorge doesn't automatically make it right.

Comment: @sg3s Does the solution work?

Comment: Yes, but it's not so much the solution as it is 'getting to that solution'. I don't know how the educational institutions where you live handle this but here it is commonly forbidden to just give the answer on a math test and there is heavier weight on the explanation of how you got to that answer (how you calculated it) than the answer itself. Yes, in cases, you could in theory get all answers wrong and still score a positive mark because you explained yourself in a correct manner.

Comment: @sg3s Ok. Next time i'll take another approach and i hope you  like it and don't downvote it.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to send javascript to the browser send just a unix timestamp and make a date with that on the server

PHP

```
echo json_encode(array('start' => mktime(date("Y",strtotime($start_date)))));
```

JS

```
var val = JSON.parse(json);
var date = new Date(val['start']);
```